# Limitation on using PrincipalContext & DomainContext, to retrive Active directory users

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have added the following code inside my asp.net mvc web application model class, to retrive the current AD users:-

```
public List<DomainContext> GetADUsers(string term=null)
        {
            List<DomainContext> results = new List<DomainContext>();
            string ADServerName = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADServerName"];
            using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, ADServerName))
            using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context)))
            {
                var searchResults = searcher.FindAll();



                foreach (Principal p in searchResults)
                {
                   if (term == null || p.SamAccountName.ToString().ToUpper().StartsWith(term.ToUpper()))
                   {
                    DomainContext dc = new DomainContext();
                    dc.DisplayName = p.DisplayName;
                    dc.UserPrincipalName = p.UserPrincipalName;
                    dc.Name = p.Name;
                    dc.SamAccountName = p.SamAccountName ;
                    dc.DistinguishedName =     p.DistinguishedName;

                    results.Add(dc);

                }
                }
            }
            return results;
        }
```

I am now on the development machine , where AD is on the same machine as the asp.net mvc web application runs. And there is no need to provide username or password to access the AD. But I have the following questions about using my above approach on production server :-

1. Will the same approach work well if the AD and the asp.net mvc (deployed on IIS ) are not on the same machine?
2. Will I be able to provide username and password to access the active directory?
3. What are the general requirements I should achieve to be able to allow the Domaincontext class to access AD on remote servers ?

Thanks I advance for any help.
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're asking if you're able to use the same code if the web server is not apart of the Active Directory domain. [`PrincipalContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341016%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does have an overload for username and password to allow for credentials to be used to connect, instead of relying on the machine having enough permissions to read from the directory.

As for permissions, grant as few as possible. I would get your system administrator involved to create a the account. You maybe able to use Service Accounts which were introduced in Windows Server 2008 to allow for the authentication to happen.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but where i should create the service account on the AD machine or on the machine that host the MVc web application ?

Comment: @johnG You would need to create the service account within Active Directory, and then give that username and password to the `PrincipalContext`.